How to realize tsaregular function of Matlab in python?
I know the tsa function and can make a similar function in Python.
But I'm having trouble understanding tsaregular1 :Regular signal of a time-synchronous averaged signal.
I want to program one in Python.
Could someone kindly explain it to me?

There are links to 4 reference papers, as well as an "algorithms" section on the documentation section you've linked. Have you tried to implement anything from those which you could show us? This question is currently pretty broad, and would be improved by showing what you've tried and specifically which part you're stuck on

In case you did not see https://www.mathworks.com/help/predmaint/ug/filter-time-synchronous-averaged-signals.html

Wolfie and dankal444, Thanks so much. Following your link, I find the references. I need some time to read them before next question.

TSA can be decomposed into two signals: TSA-regular and TSA-difference. TSA-regular is similar to the approximate wavelet, while TSA-difference is similar to the details of the wavelet. 
The function  time synchronous averaged(tsa)
 in MATLAB returns a time-synchronous average of a signal. 
For example, tsa =  (x, fs, tp) returns a time-synchronous average of a signal x sampled at a rate fs on the pulse times specified in tp

Yes, I can understand the tsa, and there is a python realization at https://github.com/DavidRaus/pyTSA
I also want to know how to calculate tsa-regular and tsa-difference in details.
Could you give me more information on it? Thank you.

Hi CHaitanya, Your answer is great but it's more on descriptive side of things. It will be great if you can reframe your answer to include description as well as implementation details for tsa-regular and tsa-difference
